# How do I send the chosen cell array to another view in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to send an `NSMutableArray` of the chosen cell to another view when a cell is clicked. I have the array of the chosen cell, but I can't get it to pass over.

"SearchResultsModalTableViewController.m"

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *aVenue = [self.venues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    DetailSearchResultViewController *detailVC =[[DetailSearchResultViewController alloc]init];
    detailVC.venueInfo = aVenue;
    NSLog(@"%@",aVenue);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your expectation, and what is actually happening? You just init another ViewController, but there's not "add to subview" or "push on navigation controller"

Comment: You need to do the work in prepareForSegue:

Comment: `but I can't get it to pass over`[Is gandalf blocking it ?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJZZNHekEQw). You are not doing anything with the new view controller which you initiated ? Is this your full code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use storyboards, you usually add segues from table cells to a destination storyboard. If that is what you are doing, then the way to deal with the selection is in the prepareForSegue: method of your view controller.

Here is an example. I am assuming that DetailSearchResultViewController in your code is a UINavigationController:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    DetailSearchResultViewController* destinationViewController = (DetailSearchResultViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *p = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
    NSUInteger idx = p.row;
    NSMutableArray *aVenue = [self.venues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];DetailSearchResultViewController *detailVC =[[DetailSearchResultViewController alloc]init];
    destinationViewController.venueInfo = aVenue;
    [super prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];
}
```